# Python Lambda function to check if a variable is NULL or empty or None

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Just trying to understand lambda function

problem:-
variable "sep" should return "-" if variable "txt" is not null or empty or none. Below is what I tried, but it's full of syntax error

```
txt="askjdh"
sep=lambda x: '-' if txt
```

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're trying to achieve here... can you explain?

Comment: if txt is null then sep = "-" ... this will be the kind of pseudo code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sep=lambda x: '-' if txt else ''`?